# UICollectionView cells appear duplicated in place after cancelled drag sessions

Tags: ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview, ios11

I’m having trouble with an obscure problem implementing local drag and drop in a UICollectionViewController.  The collection view allows dragging of items into and out of folders.  All looks and works great until cancelled drags are performed.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Collect a number of items in a drag session.
2. Cancel the drag, such as by moving to the screen edge.
3. Collect a number of items in a drag session (can contain some of the ones cancelled above).
4. Drop the items into a folder further up the collection view so that the removed items in the session cause a repositioning of the items in the cancelled drag.

The items from the cancelled session will now appear to be behind other cells.  They are not real cells though, as can be seen by rotating the iPad, these ‘ghost’ cells do not rotate correctly with the real cells they are behind, they rotate as if their origin is fixed.  They also cannot be interacted with in any manner and the data source methods do not make requests for them.  In certain situations they can also be seen after the end of the real cells by pulling the view upwards (it springs back down hiding them after letting go).  A large number of cancelled drags will also result in very poor scrolling performance, even if most of the real cells are dragged out of the collection view.

I’ve tried recreating the whole UICollectionViewController and its cell in the storyboard.  This isn’t a case of not setting all of the cells properties (I wish it was) as the ghost cells contain all elements.  They can also be overlaid multiple times depending on the operations performed.  Please see screenshots.

No issues have been found when extensively dragging and dropping hundreds of items into and out of the collection view.  It is only after a cancelled drag that the problem appears.

My best guess at this stage is that the ghost cells are part of the cancel animation that have not been removed on completion.  Given that there is no API interaction with the drag and drop animations I’m at a loss as to how to test this or fix it.

What I’m implementing in the controller:

1. itemsForBeginningDragSession and itemsForAddingToDragSession which both add a single NSItemProvider to the array returned.
2. dragPreviewParametersForItemAtIndexPath sets the visible path. (Removing this method makes no difference to the issue)
3. dropSessionDidUpdate returns either UIDropOperationMove, UICollectionViewDropIntentInsertIntoDestinationIndexPath or UIDropOperationForbidden if the session is not local.
4. performDropWithCoordinator uses performBatchUpdates and calls dropItem for each item. (The issue still exists without dropItem and with one dirty collection view reloadSections!)

What I’m using:

Xcode 9.2, various iPads with iOS 11.2 and 11.2.5

I’ve been on this for five days solid now, so any pointers in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Cells overlaid twice (similar image in three cases):

[image: Cells overlaid twice]

Cells overlaid three times (first cell has three unique images):

[image]

Cells overlaid multiple times:

[image]

Below is the code for the simpler case of dragging files into an existing folder as this makes the source easier to follow:

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDragDelegate

- (nonnull NSArray<UIDragItem *> *)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView itemsForBeginningDragSession:(nonnull id<UIDragSession>)session atIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [self itemsForDragSession:session atIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (NSArray<UIDragItem *> *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView itemsForAddingToDragSession:(id<UIDragSession>)session atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath point:(CGPoint)point
{
    return [self itemsForDragSession:session atIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (nonnull NSArray<UIDragItem *> *)itemsForDragSession:(nonnull id<UIDragSession>)session atIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray<UIDragItem *> *dragItems = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (self.isEditing)
    {
        return dragItems;
    }

    DrawingFile *drawingFile = [[WDDrawingManager sharedInstance] drawingFileAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    if (drawingFile && drawingFile.isDrawing)
    {
        NSItemProvider *itemProvider = [[NSItemProvider alloc] init];
        UIDragItem *dragItem = [[UIDragItem alloc] initWithItemProvider:itemProvider];

        [dragItems addObject:dragItem];
    }

    return dragItems;
}

- (UIDragPreviewParameters *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView dragPreviewParametersForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DrawingThumbnailCell *cell = (DrawingThumbnailCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *thumbnailView = cell.thumbnailImage;
    CGRect rect = [cell convertRect:thumbnailView.bounds fromView:thumbnailView];

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:7];

    UIDragPreviewParameters *parameters = [[UIDragPreviewParameters alloc] init];
    parameters.visiblePath = path;

    return parameters;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDropDelegate

- (UICollectionViewDropProposal *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView dropSessionDidUpdate:(id<UIDropSession>)session withDestinationIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    return [[UICollectionViewDropProposal alloc] initWithDropOperation:UIDropOperationMove intent:UICollectionViewDropIntentInsertIntoDestinationIndexPath];
}

- (void)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView performDropWithCoordinator:(nonnull id<UICollectionViewDropCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    // Check for local only
    if (coordinator.session.localDragSession == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"performDropWithCoordinator: localDragSession == nil");
        return;
    }

    // Can only drag onto existing cells
    if (coordinator.destinationIndexPath == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"performDropWithCoordinator: destinationIndexPath == nil");
        return;
    }

    // Check for dragging back to source
    if (coordinator.items.count == 1 &&
        [coordinator.destinationIndexPath isEqual:coordinator.items.firstObject.sourceIndexPath])
    {
        NSLog(@"performDropWithCoordinator: destinationIndexPath == sourceIndexPath");
        return;
    }

    // TODO Support drop into new folder (limiting to existing keeps the test case simpler)
    DrawingFile *destinationFile = [[WDDrawingManager sharedInstance] drawingFileAtIndex:coordinator.destinationIndexPath.item];
    if (destinationFile.isDrawing == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"performDropWithCoordinator: destinationIndexPath is drawing");
        return;
    }

    // Collect the drawings and their index paths
    NSMutableArray<DrawingFile *> *sourceFiles = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray<NSIndexPath *> *sourceIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id<UICollectionViewDropItem> item in coordinator.items)
    {
        DrawingFile *sourceFile = [[WDDrawingManager sharedInstance] drawingFileAtIndex:item.sourceIndexPath.item];
        [sourceFiles addObject:sourceFile];
        [sourceIndexPaths addObject:item.sourceIndexPath];
    }

    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^()
     {
         [[WDDrawingManager sharedInstance] moveSourceFiles:sourceFiles toDestinationFile:destinationFile];
         [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:sourceIndexPaths];
     }
                             completion:nil];

    // Animate the cells moved
    DrawingThumbnailCell *cell = (DrawingThumbnailCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:coordinator.destinationIndexPath];
    CGRect thumbnailRect = [cell convertRect:cell.thumbnailImage.bounds fromView:cell.thumbnailImage];
    for (id<UICollectionViewDropItem> item in coordinator.items)
    {
        [coordinator dropItem:item.dragItem intoItemAtIndexPath:coordinator.destinationIndexPath rect:thumbnailRect];
    }

    // Update the folder drawing count
    [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[coordinator.destinationIndexPath]];
}
```

Log session 1-1.  Notice that the number of draggingItems (6) matches the number of entries in cellAppearanceStatesByIndexPaths (6) whatever that is:

```
2018-02-20 14:25:07.104388+0000 Test[644:489734] performDropWithCoordinator: coordinator[<_UICollectionViewDragAndDropController:0x104e43640 -sessionKind = unsupported; reorderedItems = (
); shadowUpdates=(
); cellAppearanceStatesByIndexPaths={
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000001800016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 12}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x112111400 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 18}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x11682e330 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000001a00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 13}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d43bc0 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 17}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x11682b090 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002600016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 19}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x1121d2760 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
};  cellAppearanceStatesByCellPointers=NSMapTable {
}
;  placeholderContexts = {(
)}; source=<_UICollectionViewDragSourceController:0x104e75d10; cv = 0x102046600; sessionState = <_UICollectionViewDragSourceControllerSessionState:0x101985890 isActive = 1; dragSession = <_UIDragSessionImpl: 0x1121efff0>>; dragState = <_UICollectionViewDragSourceControllerDragState:0x107052760 dragFrom=(0,13) draggingItems=(0,13),(0,12),(0,17),(0,18),(0,19)>>; destination=<_UICollectionViewDragDestinationController:0x10199e420; sessionState = <_UIDragDestinationControllerSessionState: state = committing; isActive = 1; isDragging = 0; isReordering = 0>; reorderingState = <_UIDragDestinationControllerReorderingState: 0x10999a210>; dropProposalState = <_UIDragDestinationControllerDropProposalState: indexPath = (0,16); proposal = <UICollectionViewDropProposal:0x104e71d50 operation = move; location = into>; didDrop = 1; effectiveIndexPath = (0,16)>>>]
```

Then followed several cancelled drags.

Log session 1-2.  Notice again that the number of draggingItems (8) matches the number of entries in cellAppearanceStatesByIndexPaths (8):

```
2018-02-20 14:25:31.132581+0000 Test[644:489734] performDropWithCoordinator: coordinator[<_UICollectionViewDragAndDropController:0x104e43640 -sessionKind = unsupported; reorderedItems = (
); shadowUpdates=(
); cellAppearanceStatesByIndexPaths={
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 16}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x11686d1d0 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 18}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d66810 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002800016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 20}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d62540 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002c00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 22}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d64d80 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 17}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d7e2a0 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002600016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 19}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x104e7a760 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002a00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 21}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x104e94fe0 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002e00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 23}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x11686efb0 - dragState = dragging; appearance = ghosted>";
};  cellAppearanceStatesByCellPointers=NSMapTable {
}
;  placeholderContexts = {(
)}; source=<_UICollectionViewDragSourceController:0x104e75d10; cv = 0x102046600; sessionState = <_UICollectionViewDragSourceControllerSessionState:0x104e9d6d0 isActive = 1; dragSession = <_UIDragSessionImpl: 0x1099b23a0>>; dragState = <_UICollectionViewDragSourceControllerDragState:0x1099b6770 dragFrom=(0,16) draggingItems=(0,16),(0,17),(0,18),(0,19),(0,23),(0,22),(0,21),(0,20)>>; destination=<_UICollectionViewDragDestinationController:0x10199e420; sessionState = <_UIDragDestinationControllerSessionState: state = committing; isActive = 1; isDragging = 0; isReordering = 0>; reorderingState = <_UIDragDestinationControllerReorderingState: 0x116d66a10>; dropProposalState = <_UIDragDestinationControllerDropProposalState: indexPath = (0,15); proposal = <UICollectionViewDropProposal:0x1099b9080 operation = move; location = into>; didDrop = 1; effectiveIndexPath = (0,15)>>>]
```

Then followed several more cancelled drags.

Log session 1-3.  This is when the overlaid cells appeared.  Key here is believe is that the number of draggingItems (4) is very different to cellAppearanceStatesByIndexPaths (25) which contains many index paths that were not dragged in that session:

```
2018-02-20 14:26:10.885854+0000 Test[644:489734] performDropWithCoordinator: coordinator[<_UICollectionViewDragAndDropController:0x104e43640 -sessionKind = unsupported; reorderedItems = (
); shadowUpdates=(
); cellAppearanceStatesByIndexPaths={
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000003c00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 30}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d64c00 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000003e00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 31}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x1168b8120 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000004000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 32}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d64c20 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000004200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 33}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116dda1a0 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000004400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 34}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d7e340 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000001e00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 15}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116891a30 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 16}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x11686d1d0 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000004a00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 37}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d9e300 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000007400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 58}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x11215b530 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000004c00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 38}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x11689d650 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 18}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d66810 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000004e00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 39}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x1168cfba0 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 17}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d7e2a0 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002600016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 19}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x104e7a760 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000007a00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 61}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x11215e750 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002800016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 20}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d62540 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000007c00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 62}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x1019f5ca0 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002a00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 21}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x104e94fe0 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002c00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 22}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d64d80 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000005200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 41}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d998c0 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000002e00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 23}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x11686efb0 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000005800016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 44}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x1121e6310 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000005a00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 45}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x118e57190 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000003800016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 28}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x116d65940 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000003a00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 29}" = "<_UICollectionViewCellAppearanceState:0x112144fc0 - dragState = dropped; appearance = normal>";
};  cellAppearanceStatesByCellPointers=NSMapTable {
}
;  placeholderContexts = {(
)}; source=<_UICollectionViewDragSourceController:0x104e75d10; cv = 0x102046600; sessionState = <_UICollectionViewDragSourceControllerSessionState:0x119620130 isActive = 1; dragSession = <_UIDragSessionImpl: 0x118e23a70>>; dragState = <_UICollectionViewDragSourceControllerDragState:0x119606080 dragFrom=(0,30) draggingItems=(0,30),(0,38),(0,33),(0,32)>>; destination=<_UICollectionViewDragDestinationController:0x10199e420; sessionState = <_UIDragDestinationControllerSessionState: state = committing; isActive = 1; isDragging = 0; isReordering = 0>; reorderingState = <_UIDragDestinationControllerReorderingState: 0x11939e0a0>; dropProposalState = <_UIDragDestinationControllerDropProposalState: indexPath = (0,66); proposal = <UICollectionViewDropProposal:0x1168843e0 operation = move; location = into>; didDrop = 1; effectiveIndexPath = (0,66)>>>]
```

Based on the behaviour and these logs, I believe that the internals of the the collection view drag tracking have become corrupted.  Why is the key question.

UPDATE:  This issue has successfully been reproduced in a standalone/minimal implementation with very little code here : [Test.zip](http://www.envoza.com/stackoverflow/Test.zip)

UPDATE:  This is a video showing how to reproduce the issue with the test project: [reproducing_issue.mp4](http://envoza.com/stackoverflow/reproducing_issue.mp4)

Comment: without showing the code that you use I would not expect that anyone will help you

Comment: I'm hoping that someone with experience of using drag and drop with collection views will have come across something similar or know what could be causing the issue.  I'm at the stage where I don't believe the drag and drop delegate code is at fault, but that some other part of the controller is causing a side effect.  In short if I knew which code to post, I'd know where the problem is.

Comment: can you post the implementation with the issue somewhere?

Comment: @Aris where is a good place to post it?

Comment: @Aris Good idea, see above.

Comment: @DerekPollard You can create a repo in github

Comment: @DerekPollard: Your test code working fine for me.

Comment: hello did you implement in cell : 

-(void) prepareForReuse{
    [super prepareForReuse];
}

Comment: can you share your project code ? so i can debug it ?

Comment: @NiibFouda No, I'll look into that.  What makes you ask?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan The project is linked at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @NiibFouda Are you recommending that anything needs doing in prepareForReuse?  None of the properties need releasing before cellForItemAtIndexPath, which sets everything up.  All the code is in the project linked above.

Comment: if you are using "dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier" you need to reset the cell before reusing. I will take a look at the project

Comment: @NiibFouda I don't believe that is the case if you don't need to perform any clean up.  I've added a video of the issue.

Comment: did you take a look at this link? http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/

Comment: @NiibFouda Thanks, but that is reordering.  I want to pickup multiple cells and drag them into another cell (like files into a folder) or in a future release, springload drag them to another app.  All of this works perfect until cancelled drops come into it.  Either there is a bug in collection view drag and drop for this type of operation or I'm missing something.

Comment: with one file there is no problem (no duplicated cell)
I am sure there is something missing

Comment: @NiibFouda Part of the problem is that the Apple videos and examples are all limited to dragging one cell into another collection view/app leaving the original cell in place.  I've found no reference to handling deletes after a drag in the same app.

Comment: @DerekPollard i don't find any overlapping text in your Test app. screenshot - https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnzdo2rf8d6d3jr/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20-%20iPad%20Pro%20%289.7-inch%29%20-%202018-02-27%20at%2017.04.22.png?dl=0

Comment: @NiravKotecha Keep going it will happen, try following the video.